# LaTeX in MATLAB multi-line titles

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

I need to create a two-line title in a MATLAB plot, using LaTeX in each of the lines.

```
title({'first line','second line'})
```

works, but not with LaTeX. In a single line MATLAB title, LaTeX is understood as in the example:

```
title(['$y=x^2$'],'interpreter','latex')
```

I have tried many things, but I haven't managed to have MATLAB produced a multi-line title with LaTeX in those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Up to version R2017a, using a cell array, as suggested by other answers,
>   forced left alignment. This seems to have been fixed in R2017b.

You can wrap the title in a LaTeX tabular environment:

```
figure;
plot((1:5).^2);
title('\begin{tabular}{c} first_line \\ second_line \end{tabular}', ...
      'interpreter', 'latex')
```

This will let you choose text alignment. Replace `{c}` with either `{r}` or `{l}`, for right and left aligned text, respectively.

Answer (score 7):

If you run

```
title({'$y=x^2$','$y=x^2$'},'interpreter','latex')
```

you will get a two-line title with correct LaTeX-ification.

Comment: Perhaps you were trying to execute some ill-formed LaTeX formatting?  Try posting the actual LaTeX commands that failed if you are still having trouble.  Also, post which version of MATLAB you are using.

Comment: Yeah, much more cleaner than the other solutions. Nice job.

Comment: This accepted answer lets the user choose text alignment (centred alignment in his example), while the answer above does not. Using a cell array will force (the often undesired) left alignment. This is likely a bug.

Comment: Using a cell array uses centered alignment in R2020b.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to create the string for the [`title`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html), explicitly with a newline character, `'\n'`.

```
title(sprintf('$y=x^3$\n$sin(x)$'), 'interpreter', 'latex');
```